# How to expand Python Pandas Dataframe in linearly spaced increments

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Beginner question:

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
x1   y1    x2    y2
0    0     2     2
10   10    12    12
```

and I want to expand that dataframe by half units along the x and y coordinates to look like this:

```
x1   y1    x2    y2      Interpolated_X      Interpolated_Y
0    0     2     2            0                    0
0    0     2     2            0.5                  0.5
0    0     2     2            1                    1
0    0     2     2            1.5                  1.5
0    0     2     2            2                    2
10   10    12    12           10                   10
10   10    12    12           10.5                 10.5
10   10    12    12           11                   11
10   10    12    12           11.5                 11.5
10   10    12    12           12                   12
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I know how to expand rows like this is through `groupby.apply`. May be faster to use something like `itertuples` in pandas but it will be a little more complicated code (keep that in mind if your data-set is larger).

`groupby` the index which will send each row to my `apply` function (your index has to be unique for each row, if its not just run `reset_index`). I can return a DataFrame from my `apply` therefore we can expand from one row to multiple rows.

caveat, your `x2-x1` and `y2-y1` distance must be the same or this won't work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def expand(row):
    row = row.iloc[0] # passes a dateframe so this gets reference to first and only row
    xdistance = (row.x2 - row.x1)
    ydistance = (row.y2 - row.y1) 
    xsteps = np.arange(row.x1, row.x2 + .5, .5) # create steps arrays
    ysteps = np.arange(row.y1, row.y2 + .5, .5)
    return (pd.DataFrame([row] * len(xsteps)) # you can expand lists in python by multiplying like this [val] * 3 = [val, val, val]
              .assign(int_x = xsteps, int_y = ysteps))

(df.groupby(df.index) # "group" on each row
   .apply(expand) # send row to expand function
   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)) # groupby gives us an extra index we don't want
```

starting df

```
x1   y1    x2    y2
0    0     2     2
10   10    12    12
```

ending df

```
    x1  y1  x2  y2  int_x   int_y
0   0   0   2   2   0.0     0.0
0   0   0   2   2   0.5     0.5
0   0   0   2   2   1.0     1.0
0   0   0   2   2   1.5     1.5
0   0   0   2   2   2.0     2.0
1   10  10  12  12  10.0    10.0
1   10  10  12  12  10.5    10.5
1   10  10  12  12  11.0    11.0
1   10  10  12  12  11.5    11.5
1   10  10  12  12  12.0    12.0
```